# What does the Lock in the Blue Circle next to my Quest mean?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I was playing Lord of the Rings Online, and I noticed a lock icon in a blue circle next to a quest in my tracker.  What does this mean?  Is it related to the quest title being blue in the quest menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I determined by experimentation that the icon indicates that a quest is "locked" on the quest tracker, i.e. placed there manually, as opposed to the "free floating" or automatically displayed quests.  Quests placed on the tracker manually will not be removed until they are finished or manually removed.

It is completely independent of quest title color.

Comment: To expand on this: Because you placed it there, manually, it will not be replaced by updating another quest. You will have to finish it or manually remove it.